# Oracle SQL Error Message

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a table, i have created various tables in the same format which have successfully compiled.

here is what i am trying to create:

```
Create table property_table of property_t(
property# Primary Key)
Nested table relates store as relates_appoint_table;
```

and i am receiving the following error message:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
Create table property_table of property_t(
property# Primary Key)
Nested table relates store as relates_appoint_table
Error at Command Line:3 Column:14
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

hope somebody out there can help

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are using? The above is not valid DDL.

Comment: certainly a hash mark `#` is not valid in SQL, is it?

Comment: hi, this is the actual code we are using and has worked for previous table creations,

Comment: Create table property_tab of property_t (
Primary key (property#))
Nested table relates store as relates_appoint_table;

Comment: hash has been used previously and has work qarma

Comment: Can you please find me documentation which suggests that a `#` is valid syntax?

Comment: Please post a *complete* example (e.g. the definition of `property_t` is missing).

Comment: it is not a syntax function, it is an attribute name and has worked for all other tables

Comment: Frank, create or replace type property_t as object(
property# char(4),
dateOfReg date,
propType varchar2(40),
bedrooms char(10),
recepRooms char(10),
bathrooms char(10),
garage varchar2(10),
garden varchar2(10),
regionArea varchar2(30),
pAddressLine1 varchar2(30),
pAddressLine2 varchar2(30),
pTown varchar2(50),
price varchar2(20),
relatesTo ref appointment_t);
/

Comment: Are you really using `Oracle database`? As others have said, it is NOT a valid DDL syntax to create table. If you do not agree, please post your **SQL*Plus** session, **SHOW** the proof that the DDL actually succeds in creating the table, as you stated that *it worked for all other tables*.

Comment: If in doubt, read the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402  especially: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#CEGEDHJE

Comment: yes oracle 11g object-relational SQL developer

Comment: Get rid of the word "relates" after "nested table" and try it again. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Wouldn't removing `relates` bust the syntax and cause `ORA-00905`?

Comment: removing relates doesn't work?

Comment: Uni, you have syntactical errors in your code. It will not work at all until you resolve those.

Comment: what are the syntactical errors please I am going mad

Comment: @mmmmmpie - for documentation saying `#` is valid, see [the seventh object naming rule](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129). Oracle recommend not using it, but it's valid, and used in system tables of course *8-)

Comment: @UniMe - the definition of `appointment_t`, and a table type of that object type if you already have one, would be useful; can you edit the type definitions into the question though? I'm not sure if you want the property type to include a nested table of appointments, or nested table of refs to appointments, or a single ref to an appointment. You're mixing them up at the moment.

Comment: @AlexPoole i want the property table to include a nested table of appointments. I have not yet created a table type of appointment_t, does this need to be done first?

Comment: @UniMe - yes, the table type has to exist before you can use it in the `property_t` definition, and before you can create a table based on that. I demonstrated that in my answer though.

Comment: @alexpoole  have tried your solution and it doesn't work?

Comment: @UniMe - you'll need to be more specific; it works in the sample SQL Fiddles in the answer. If you have follow-up questions about that then please comment on that answer, not on the question, as they lose relevance here. Adding your actual `appointment_t` definition to the question  might still be useful (as an edit not a comment; and include any other types too).

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem is just a name mismatch, which is what the error messages says really; the line and position point to the word `relates` and the ORA-00904 tells you it isn't valid. Your `property_t` type is defined with `relatesTo ref appointment_t` but in your `property_table` creation you refer to `relates`, not `relatesTo`.

But then you seem to have a type mismatch. `appointment_t` is an object type, not a table type, so a nested table clause doesn't make sense; you'd then get `ORA-22912: specified column or attribute is not a nested table type`. You seem to be confusing an object type with a table type somewhere along the way.

It isn't clear if you want that to be a reference to a single object type, or to a table of appointments (or refs to appointments) - I think a table is maybe more likely, as you'd expect multiple viewings for a property for sale (?), in which case you'd need an additional type as a table of appointments:

```
create or replace type appointment_tab_t as table of appointment_t
/
```

... or since your originally had a ref to a single appointment, as a table of refs to appointments:

```
create or replace type appointment_tab_t as table of ref appointment_t
/
```

Either way your `property_t` type would have:

```
..., relatesTo appointment_tab_t)
```

... then your table would be created with:

```
Create table property_table of property_t(
property# Primary Key)
Nested table relatesTo store as relates_appoint_table;

Table property_table created.
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0ee3/1) (or [with `table of ref`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83ea6/1)) with a made-up appointment type.

The alternative is to leave the `property_t` as you have it with a ref to a single appointment:

```
..., relatesTo ref appointment_t)
```

... and drop the nested table clause:

```
Create table property_table of property_t(
property# Primary Key)
/

Table property_table created.
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc2271/1).